# Simple controller with Magento 1.8.0

Tags: php, magento, routes

I am newbie in Magento world, and I want to create simple controller like described [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config). But when I put into my browser I getting 404 error. I try to find solution in web but I didn't. Can somebody help me please? If you need some peace of code just say to me. Thanks!

P.S. Module is active, I check in admin dashboard.

Comment: Navigate the /var/www/html/magento/var/log/system.log file

Comment: can your share your code??

Comment: share ur code for understanding? and directory structure too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory structure should look as follows:

> app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php
>   app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then create a file to activate the module (at path app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create a file at

app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
public function indexAction() {

        echo 'Hello Index!';

    }
}
```

Browse in your browser

```
 http://example.com/index.php/helloworld
```

That's it.